# React state conflict with javascript "document.getElementById" function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-state

I have this function in my React web application:

```
const handleRateLightSelection = (cardId, rateId) => {

setRateLightSelected(0);

if (lastSelectedLightCardId != -1 && lastSelectedLightCardId != cardId) {

  document.getElementById('lightBox-' + lastSelectedLightCardId).classList.remove("rate-box-grosso-light");
  document.getElementById('lightBox-' + lastSelectedLightCardId + '-check').classList.add("d-none");

}

if (lastSelectedLightCardId == -1 || lastSelectedLightCardId != cardId) {

  document.getElementById('lightBox-' + cardId).classList.add("rate-box-grosso-light");
  document.getElementById('lightBox-' + cardId + '-check').classList.remove("d-none");

  setRateLightSelected(rateId);

} else {

  var boxSelection = document.getElementById('lightBox-' + cardId).classList.contains("rate-box-grosso-light");

  if (boxSelection) {

    document.getElementById('lightBox-' + cardId).classList.remove("rate-box-grosso-light");
    document.getElementById('lightBox-' + cardId + '-check').classList.add("d-none");

    setRateLightSelected(0);

  } else {

    document.getElementById('lightBox-' + cardId).classList.add("rate-box-grosso-light");
    document.getElementById('lightBox-' + cardId + '-check').classList.remove("d-none");

    setRateLightSelected(rateId);

  }

}

lastSelectedLightCardId = cardId;
}
```

Using `document.getElementById` function, I'm handling boxes styles when users select them. All is working fine by now.

In retrospect, I've added `setRateLightSelected` state to handle the selection ID save and send it to my backend in a later time. After I've added `this`, the `document.getElementById` functions stopped working and I don't understand why?

Comment: In a React app, you're not supposed to do this at all; the flow instead is: user interactions change state -> component re-renders using updated state. Simply use expressions in your JSX that compose the list of classes based on state. Also note that state changes are async and batched together, calling the same setState functions multiple times in quick succession will not work like you expect it to.

Comment: Where does ``lastSelectedLightCardId`` is declared ? Btw you shouldn't play with classes that way ... Just compare state values in order to add a class

Comment: Please don't **use** random boldfacing in your **posts**, it makes **them** hard **to** read. :-) And as Chris G said, this is just fundamentally now how you do this sort of thing in React (though it's perfectly understandable why people start off in this direction even in React stuff when learning it).

Comment: Hi @ChrisG, thank you so much for your answer! Can you please explain better what do you mean with "Simply use expressions in your JSX that compose the list of classes based on state."

I know that the React States are made to handle the user flow, but if I use "normal variables", these are not totally visible in my JSX (for ex. to handle view/hide of a "continue button", exc...)

Comment: Every state variable should be visible in the entire function. It sounds like you're looking for conditional rendering, a simple example is `{isVisible && <div>blah</div>}`. As for the class thing, I use: `const classes = ["card"]; if (x) classes.push("d-none");` Now I have an array containing all the classes. In JSX, I do `className={classes.join(" ")}`. Also, id composition is  bad practice; you most likely have an array of cards; you should deal with them based on the array index directly, not via `id`s containing running numbers.

Comment: @ChrisG thank u, it's a really great solution! But, how can I improve that when I've to handle dynamic card classes? To explain myself better, my cards are mapped at runtime with the data on my DB. I've to handle my "selection style classes" one card at a time when the user clicks on a certain card.
How can I adapt your suggestion?

Comment: You should already be rendering your cards using something like `{cardArray.map(card => <...>)}`. Handling the state of a card is just a question of organizing the component's state in a way that you can change and read the state of an individual card at any time.